# I open the browser with Selenium, but upon opening the browser, it closes immediately.I would like it to stay open, How can I achieve that?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def open_chrome(self):        
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://www.google.com.br')

def open_youtube(self):
    youtube = webdriver.Chrome()
    youtube.get('https://www.youtube.com.br')
```

I tried using sleep, but it didn't work well. The program became slow, and the performance was poor.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is automatically closed at the end of the script. To prevent this, one option is to put a breakpoint on the final line of your script to stop it before it's closed.

---

Additional feedback...

Rather than creating a separate method to open each site, `open_chrome()` (which is actually opening google) and `open_youtube()`, instead just change/pass the URL... the rest of the code should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/#keeping-browser-open